Microchip Libero SOC warning: Sharing sequential element Cmd_TimErr. Add a syn_preserve attribute to the element to prevent sharing
I am programming an FPGA (A3PE3000-FG484) and I get this warning when I ran synthesis in Libero:

Sharing sequential element Cmd_TimErr. Add a syn_preserve attribute to the element to prevent sharing.

What does this warning mean?
I use Libero v11.9 Sp6 and Synplify Pro L-2016.09M-SP1-5, Build 264R, Oct 26 2017.
